# How to get reference to clarity datagrid from typescript

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

This might be more of an angular question, but I'm trying to resize the clarity datagrid after loading data (and dynamically showing/hiding columns) but I keep getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined

component.html

```
<clr-datagrid #contactsGrid>
[...]
</clr-datagrid>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Datagrid } from "clarity-angular";

export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('contactsGrid') datagrid: Datagrid;
    //@ViewChild('Datagrid') datagrid: Datagrid; //This doesn't work either

    constructor( ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        [...]
        this.datagrid.resize(); //this.datagrid is undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your sample code above is correct, perhaps there is more going on? Do you have a more complete example to share that demonstrates the actual issue live?

You can see a demo here of getting the reference for a datagrid. https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-datagrid-brfwx9?file=app/launches/launches.component.ts

The template has:

```
<clr-datagrid [(clrDgSelected)]="selected" #datagridRef>
```

Then the controller has:

```
export class LaunchesComponent  {
  @ViewChild('datagridRef') datagrid: Datagrid;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.datagrid); // Defined
  }
```

If you only have one Datagrid, you don't need to add a hook in the HTML

```
export class LaunchesComponent  {
  @ViewChild(Datagrid) datagrid: Datagrid;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.datagrid); // Defined
  }
```

It looks like your code was passing `'Datagrid'` (a string) instead of `Datagrid`(a reference to the constructor)

Comment: There was an *ngIf on my datagrid, that seems to have been the issue. Thanks.